# Error in custom php function doesn't exist

Tags: php, functions, theme-development, hooks

I was able to successfully set the default page template for a new page, when there is not yet a defined template to be **member_home_page.php**.

This works perfectly on my local environment but when I uploaded the code to my site on WP Engine I get this error at the top of the admin page edit screen for WordPress.

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'set_default_page_template' not found or invalid function name in /nas/content/staging/pmbus/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php on line 288
```

Both on local and live deployments the function works. But on local I don't get the error, only live. Below is the function, i'm just not sure why i'm getting this warning only on live. Thanks in advance.

```
function set_page_template_default() {

    global $post;

    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type
        && 0 != count( get_page_templates( $post ) )
        && get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) != $post->ID // Not the page for listing posts
        && '' == $post->page_template // Only when page_template is not set
    ) {
        $post->page_template = 'member_home_page.php';
    }

}

add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'set_page_template_default', 1);
```

Comment: was the function formerly named `set_default_page_template`, then you changed it to `set_page_template_default` ? I'm guessing here: but if thats the case, WPEngine is likely showing you a cache of the old error. These 'dedicated WP hosts' have really good cache's, ensure they're off while developing for less headaches.

Comment: Thank you, for some reason it was looking for both set_page_default_template and set_default_page_template. I just made an empty function for the opposite that wont be called.

Answer (score 0):

You get an error because it's looking for function named as `set_default_page_template` while you seems to have function named `set_page_template_default`.

I'm not sure you either don't have a function named `set_default_page_template` or you later renamed it. but that's the error. WP cannot find your hook because it doesn't exist.

you should either rename your `set_default_page_template` to `set_default_page_template` (if this is the function what you need) or you should create a new function and name it as `set_default_page_template`